# I have a hybrid (part ASP, part ASPX) web app. If the user spends too long on the ASPX side, they get logged out on the ASP side. How can I fix this?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript, webforms, asp-classic

If the user spends too long on the ASPX side of the app without visiting an ASP page, their ASP session times out and the next time they visit an ASP page, they get logged out and have to log in again. Is there any way to count both sides of the app toward the logout timer? Rather than having a separate logout timer for each as we have now?

Answer (score 3):

As you have discovered Classic ASP and ASP.net have separate session objects, and it can be a pain. It's even more annoying if you want to share session variables.  The default timeout for both is 20 minutes - you can specify other values if you wish.

What I would do in your situation is to use zero size iframes.  The best place to put one is in the .master template if your app has one.  The iframe would point to a classic asp page whose sole function is to keep the Classic ASP session live.  If necessary you could also do it the other way around and have iframes in your classic pages pointing to an asp.net script

Comment: That's a clever solution! I'll bring that up with team members and see if that's something we can do. I don't think we have a master page and we have a LOT of asp and aspx pages, so this might take a while...

Comment: Out of interest how does your app handle logging in in the first place, it clearly needs to set both a Classic and a .net session cookie?

Comment: It looks like we are passing along all the session variables that are being set by the ASP.NET login to an ASP page which saves them off as its own cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function instead of a session cookie that checks a database entry of when the user logged in, and if the user is logged in, `UPDATE` the current login timer to "now".